Abstract function's copy constructor deleted, class inherited from this class gives error
Given header files named Point.h:
#pragma once 
struct Point { 
        double x, y; 
};

and Shape.h:
#pragma once
#include "Point.h"
#include <vector>
class Shape {
public:
        Shape(const Shape&) =delete;
        Shape& operator=(const Shape&) =delete;

        virtual Point center() const =0;
        virtual void move(Point to) =0;

        virtual void draw() const = 0;
        virtual void rotate(int angle) = 0;

        virtual ~Shape() {}
};

void rotate_all(std::vector<Shape*>& v, int angle);

with the source code named Shape.cpp:
#include <iostream> 
#include "Shape.h" 
#include "Point.h"
void rotate_all(std::vector<Shape*>& v, int angle)
{
        for(auto p : v)
                p->rotate(angle);
}

I cannot figure out the reason why the header file named Circle.h:
#pragma once
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Point.h"
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
        Circle(Point p, int rad) : x{p}, r{rad} {};

        Point center() const override
        {
                return x;
        }
        void move(Point to) override
        {
                x = to;
        }

        void draw() const override;
        void rotate(int) override {}
private:
        Point x;
        int r;
};

with the source file named Circle.cpp:
#include "Circle.h"
#include <iostream>
void Circle::draw() const
{
        std::cout << "Circle drawn!" << '\n';
}

gives the following error:
Circle.h: In constructor ‘Circle::Circle(Point, int)’:
Circle.h:6:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘Shape::Shape()’
    6 |         Circle(Point p, int rad) : x{p}, r{rad} {};
      |                                               ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:
Shape.h:6:9: note: candidate: ‘Shape::Shape(const Shape&)’ (deleted)
    6 |         Shape(const Shape&) =delete;
      |         ^~~~~
Shape.h:6:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

I tried deleting this line in Shape.h:
Shape(const Shape&) =delete;
and it did fix the problem, however nowhere in Circle.h calls Shape() in Shape.h.

Here is a much simpler [mcve].

Your definition of Circles constructor implicitly (in its initialiser list) requires a default constructor of Shape, since your definition is equivalent to Circle(Point p, int rad) : Shape(), x{p}, r{rad} {};.    deleteing a copy constructor of Shape has an effect of suppressing implicit generation of Shape's default constructor (which accepts no arguments).    Either modify Circles constructors so their initialiser lists call an existing constructor of Shape, or ensure Shape has a default constructor (e.g. is explicitly defined, or by Shape() = default).

Just some side-notes: try to use meaningful and relevant variable names. A member like r for your circle's radius is not a very meaningful name, despite that being typical in math notation. Even worse, the variable x to describe a shape's position is misleading because x typically refers to one element of a 2D (x,y) position. Calling the position itself x is just confusing. Your radius is an integer type, whereas your positions are floating-point, which seems a bit unusual. It's hard to understand why you wouldn't also use a floating-point value to describe the radius.

This constructor
Circle(Point p, int rad) : x{p}, r{rad} {};

implicitly calls Shape::Shape() (the default constructor). The default constructor is auto-generated if there are no other constructors. When you add
Shape(const Shape&) =delete;

Shape::Shape() is not generated anymore. The diagnostic is misleading: the compiler tries the only other constructor, Shape(const Shape&), but, instead of complaining about mismatching arguments, it complaints about the constructor being deleted.
The fix is simple: add Shape() = default; in class Shape.
